# How can we remove incoming bluetooth file request prompt in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

We are working on android application which connect with Raspberry Pi device via Classic Bluetooth.

We want to capture Image file from camera connected with Raspberry Pi and pass to connected android device which are paired with Raspberry Pi.

It was display popup at android side for incoming file request every time when file will come from Raspberry Pi but we are looking for solution for how can we remove or bypass incoming bluetooth file request prompt in android.

We want to auto accept incoming bluetooth file on android with paired device.We don't want to click accept button.

[image: click here to show popup image]

We also know few solutions which are not suitable

1. We don't want to go with BLE due to limitation of data transfer rate in single go for large file.
2. Image convert to Base 64 of image but it will take long time for transfer more than 2 MB image file.
3. We found one solution which need root android phone but we can't say to user about root phone.

We want to use Classic Bluetooth.

Comment: Maybe you can use GATT over Bluetooth Classic? Or just use a standard Bluetooth socket?

Comment: Currently i m using standard Bluetooth socket for communicate phone with raspberry pi and i m sending captured image from raspberry pi to phone using bluetooth GATT objex object push service.